# Overridable events of control (Android studio)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adk

How can I know what override events a controls has?

First of all I have search Google and android api for this thing but not successful.

If I further elaborate my question I would give an example of Visual studio C# in which If I drag a control and I can view all properties and events of this control and if double click on any event it automatically write that event for me.
Now if I look for documentation I can find these http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

Also If I have any shortcut key for implement events of any control. If I can do this in eclipse that will also helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Mac, you can try `ctrl + O` to get a list of methods that can be overridden, or `cmd + F12`x2 to get a list of inherited members.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Search for `Override methods` and `File structure popup` in these documents.

Comment: Yes I know this before, this is overridden methods not events?
giving you an example
if I am looking for seekbar all events how can I get to know that it has setOnSeekBarChangeListener event
yes intelegence can help me but it give too big lest and I have to search each control to find events.
As I said before...

And thanks for short cut keys...

Comment: If you are using Java to develop Android then surely all events are methods right? If you need to check the methods available for a widget, say `Button`, open its source file in Android Studio and use the shortcut above will do the trick?

Comment: Yes you are almost right, because I can find most of events here, but I think you didn't get my question.
I can view most of events here but not all also it is very difficult for a beginner to pick right event for his control, it should work like if I select a control and pressed  Ctl + o it then show me overridable event of that control.
Also as I said not all event listed I can't find addTextChangedListener , setOnSeekBarChangeListener and sure more events will be missing....

Comment: I agree, when I first started I also struggled with trying to find what are available to use.